# Android Privacy Policy Language

Tags: android, privacy-policy

Is it compulsory for the privacy policy to be in a language in which I'm deploying the app? I'm deploying to Spanish language but my privacy policy is in English. Will play store complain or is it fine to have the privacy policy in English?

I didn't find any info on this on the internet so asking here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Off-topic, see posts: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/295004)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the privacy policy in the intended target audience' language was rejected by Play. I've translated it into English and pasted the contents into the same page below the initial content, then they accepted.

Just saying.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks for that! I think the privacy policy in other languages should only be referenced inside the app for the users then. And while publishing use the English one?

Comment: We say thanks here by upvoting and/or accepting the answer. As for my users, I don't think they care much.